# Rotating player is messing up my movement

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote a simple player movement script which moves my player like this:

```
private void MovePlayer()
{

    // Initialize Directions For Player Movement
    movement = transform.right * horizontal * playerSpeed + transform.forward * vertical * playerSpeed;

    // Move Player
    rb.AddForce(movement, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

and I am trying to rotate my player towards the axes, for example if the player is pressing a the horizontal will be -1 and I want to rotate my player left `horizontal * 90f`, now when I try this, my horizontal axis is acting like my vertical, if I press A it will bring my player backwards, if I press D it will do the same thing, this is how I rotate the player:

```
// buggy code:
private void RotatePLayerTowardsAxis()
{
    // Rotate PLayer Horizontaly
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, horizontal * 90, 0f);
}
```

is there a way I can do this?

Edit:

The vertical is still pushing me up and down.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to check if you are looking at the scene in Local or Global view. Check your axes in Local mode:

[image]

If your character model faces towards the blue axis, then everything should be okay.

If you want to rotate your character only by 90 degrees all the time, then it can be done somehow like this:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
```

You can use the following as well, but this might not fit your needs:

```
transform.Rotate(transform.up, 90);
```

This will make your character rotate by 90 degrees AROUND the up axis. If you want it to rotate always around the world up axis:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 90);
```

However, `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);` might be better for you, as it always "resets" the rotation when you overwrite it. This will make the character fixed to a direction. So if you press left, the charater will always look into the left by 90 degree. And if you press right after the left turn, your character will do a 180° turn instead of looking forward. I hope you get what I'm trying to say. This means, that your character will be bound to the world axis instead of its own. To modify this (if you want to), write something like this:

```
transform.rotation += Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
```

Hope I could help!